# How to generate terraform execution plan using ansible role?

Tags: ansible, terraform

Terraform module provided by ansible works well for creating aws resources with S3 backend config for statefile.
but not able to get the `terraform plan` output using this module.
We want the output should list something like:
`Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.`
and give details of the resources to be created/destroyed/changed

Have tried below task in ansible, but not able to generate output as expected.

below is ansible task for creating plan:

```sh
- name: "create file"
  shell: "touch {{playbook_dir}}/tfplan && ls -larth ../terraform/{{role_name}} "

- name: "Run terraform project with plan file"
  terraform:
    state: planned
    backend_config:
      bucket: "{{bootstrap_prefix}}-{{aws_account_type}}-{{caller_facts.account}}"
      region: "{{ bootstrap_aws_region }}"
      kms_key_id: "{{ kms_id.stdout }}"
      encrypt: true
      workspace_key_prefix: "{{ app_parent }}-{{ app_name }}"
      key: "terraform.tfstate"
    force_init: true
    project_path: "../terraform/{{role_name}}"
    plan_file: "{{playbook_dir}}/tfplan"
    variables:
      app_name: "{{ app_name }}"
    workspace: "{{ app_env }}"
```

Output of above ansible task:

```sh
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "command": "/usr/local/bin/terraform -lock=true /root/project/ansible/tfplan",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backend_config": {
                "bucket": "XXXXXXXX2440728499",
                "encrypt": true,
                "key": "terraform.tfstate",
                "kms_key_id": "XXXXXXXX",
                "region": "XXXXXXXX",
                "workspace_key_prefix": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "binary_path": null,
            "force_init": true,
            "lock": true,
            "lock_timeout": null,
            "plan_file": "/root/project/ansible/tfplan",
            "project_path": "../terraform/applications",
            "purge_workspace": false,
            "state": "planned",
            "state_file": null,
            "targets": [],
            "variables": {
                "app_name": "application"

            },
            "variables_file": null,
            "workspace": "uat"
        }
    },
    "outputs": {},
    "state": "planned",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": [],
    "workspace": "uat"
}
```

It works fine with `state: present` (`terraform apply`) , but want it to work with `state:planned` (`terraform plan`)

Comment: It appears [that issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/39689) [was fixed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/52004) in Feb; can you try ansible 2.8.0 and see if it behaves correctly for you?

Comment: Many Thanks...It solved with ansible 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

In [current ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/terraform_module.html): `To just run a terraform plan, use check mode.`

In addition, you should add to `terraform` module parameters:

```
- name: "Run terraform project with plan file"
  terraform:
    state: planned
    check_mode: true
```